# Retrieve the Inapp purchase of particular user from google play using billing client

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have used Billing client to handle inapp purchase. Once a non-consumable product is purchased, after acknowledging I can save a value in shared preferences.

**Constraints**
If the user clear the app data or uninstall the app, It will be lost. How to handle this scenario.

**Note**
I am not convinced to save it in cloud. pls suggest how to fetch it from Google play each time the app starts using billing Client.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `billingClient.queryPurchases()` to get what items the user owns when the app is first started after installation.

Then you can save it in SharedPreferences but I recommend to call  `billingClient.queryPurchases()` periodically to update the list. This is still more important if the item is a subscription to know if it is still active or has expired.

And do not forget to verify the signature of the data received to avoid fraud.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

> You should call billingClient.queryPurchases() to get what items the user owns when the app is first started after installation.

But `billingClient.queryPurchases()` according to documentation:

> Only active subscriptions and non-consumed one-time purchases are returned.

So how you get the purchased, already consumed items (not subscriptions but IAP)?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30920640)